# Google Test : Undefined references error- base class functions

Tags: googletest

This is my code:

```
class Variable
{
public:
    int functiona(void) {
        int x = 1;
        return x;
    }

};

class Variable1 : public Variable
{
    //something
};

class Variable2 : public Variable1
{
    //call function
    int r = functiona();

    //other functions
};


TEST(Variable2, test100)
{
    // - SET UP THE MOCKS -

    xxx_Mock::xxx_ExpectAndReturn(true);

    // - ACTUAL TEST(S) -
    Variable2 * variableg = new Variable2();

    variableg->otherFunctions();


    // -- --

    // -- Cleanup --
    delete variableg;


    EXPECT_VERIFY_MOCK();
}
```

When I try to implement Google test UT for "other functions of class Variable2" during "compilation/make", I am getting error that says:

*undefined reference to functiona*.

Comment: You question is unclear. What does `int r = functiona();` mean? Is this statement inside a body of another function? As it stands, this code will certainly not compile.

Comment: Yes.My Actual code is too too lengthy. This int r = functiona(); is inside another function.

Comment: I am sorry but no one will be able to help you like this. With code like this, there is too much room for guessing. You need to post your entire code, or strip it down to create a MVCE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if the code is too long.